# XML Warning, Namespace not bound

Tags: xsd, phpunit

I'm getting this warning in PHPStorm for a PHPUnit test but am not sure what it's talking about?

`Namespace not bound`

```
<phpunit colors="true" bootstrap="./tests/bootstrap.php">
    <testsuite name="IniParserTest">
        <directory>./tests/Test</directory>
    </testsuite>
</phpunit>
```

Comment: Did you find an answer to this question? I get this also via **Code Inspection**.

Answer (score 2):

You have to specificy the XML Schema in the opening  element node, like to:

```
<phpunit colors="true" bootstrap="./tests/bootstrap.php" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="http://schema.phpunit.de/3.7/phpunit.xsd">
    <testsuite name="IniParserTest">
        <directory>./tests/Test</directory>
    </testsuite>
</phpunit>
```

Note the xmlns:xsi and xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation attributes in .

Now your XML should be valid and it should no longer give you the error.

Source: https://phpunit.de/manual/3.7/en/appendixes.configuration.html